# CSS footer formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, footer

I have a couple of problems in my CSS footer. Please run this snippet in Full Page to see how it lays out on a larger display (I will be making it responsive a little later. For now, please just use Full Page).

```css
.small col-md-3 {
  font-size: .8em
}
.footer-distributed {
  background-color: #34385E;
  width: 100%
}
.footer-distributed .footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-links a {
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-left-bar {
  border-left: solid;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <footer class="footer-distributed">
    <div class="row" style="height: 1em"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="footer-links">
          <a href="#">Link Number 123</a>
          <a href="#">Link Number 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link Number 3</a>
          <a href="#">Link Number 4</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 footer-left-bar">
        <div class="row footer-links">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>This information is</br>
              always three</br>
              lines long
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 footer-left-bar">
        <div class="row footer-links">
          <div class="col-md-6">BRANDING 1</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">BRANDING 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 1em"></div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

1. The 4 links on the left. I would like them to be in a left-justified cells of a 2x2 grid no matter how long the text is in them. As you can see, Link 2 is being pushed to the right because Link Number 123 is too long.
2. The 2 Branding link on the right. I would like them to be side-by-side and centered vertically such that the white separator bar matches the longer white separator bar to the left of the center column.

Can anybody offer any hints on how to accomplish this?? Thank you!!

Comment: Hey, great advice! I should have seen those. I'll try them out, thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess the comment/answer was deleted. But, it worked out great! The advice was:

1. Use a 2/2 grid of rows & columns on the left side to space out the items.
2. Use white margin lines on both sides of the center chunk, rather than trying to do left margin lines on the center and right chunks.

Vertical centering still isn't great, so I may mess around with additional answers to try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly rewritten code, without the use of Bootstrap (it's still loaded, of course, but not used for the actual footer).

```css
footer {
 background-color: #34385E;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 7em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .5em 0;
}
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.footer-links a {
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer-container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: solid;
  padding-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 0;
}
#footer-container div:nth-of-type(2) p {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#footer-container div:first-of-type {
  max-width: 30%;
}
#footer-container div:first-of-type ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  }
#footer-container div:first-of-type ul li {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#footer-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 7em;
}
#footer-container div {
  flex: 2 1 0;
}
#footer-container div:last-of-type {
  margin: auto;
  border-left: solid;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
#footer-container div:last-of-type ul li {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
   <div id="footer-container">
    <div>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="#">Link Number 123</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Number 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Number 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Number 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div>
        <p>This information is<br>
              always three<br>
              lines long
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>BRANDING 1</li>
          <li>BRANDING 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your hard work on this answers! Absolute positions are forbidden on this project, I'm afraid. Looks nice, though!

Comment: That's too bad. Just a note, though: the absolute-positioning is just to make sure the first `<ul>`, the one containing the four links, are positioned in the middle, vertically. It will also work if you decide to make the footer taller, and/or add more links to the list. It will still center the `<ul>`. So if the "no absolute positioning" is there for purely arbitrary reasons, it might be possible to argue against. Since the `<footer>` is already `position: fixed;`, the absolute-positioning will also only affect things within the footer, so...

Comment: I updated the code a little bit, because I failed to notice the border on the last container, and that the border didn't go from top to bottom. Fixed that in the revised edition. The `position: absolute;` can be lost and instead used with a manually set `margin-top` on the same element, something like `margin-top: 1em;` or perhaps `margin-top: 1.5em;` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<div>` in your HTML:

```
     <p class="footer-links">
      <div class= 'footer-left-container'>
      <div class= 'option'><a href="#">Link Number 123</a></div>
      <div class= 'option'><a href="#">Link Number 2</a></div>
      <div class= 'option'><a href="#">Link Number 3</a></div>
      <div class= 'option'><a href="#">Link Number 4</a></div>
      </div>
    </p>
```

Add in your CSS:

```
.footer-left-container{ overflow: auto; margin-left: 10px; }
.option{  width: 130px; float: left; margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 2px; }
```

As for your second question I could not understand what exactly you require.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I guess the comment/answer was deleted. But, it worked out great! The advice was:

1. Use a 2/2 grid of rows & columns on the left side to space out the
   items.
2. Use white margin lines on both sides of the center chunk,
   rather than trying to do left margin lines on the center and right
   chunks.

Vertical centering still isn't great, so I may mess around with additional answers to try that out. Thanks!